# Как получить подмассив по значению

Tags: javascript, массивы

Доброго!
Получаю в скрипте массив:

```
(
    [40] => Array
        (
            [P_1] => 1
            [P_2] => 0
            [P_3] => 1
            [P_START_TIME] => 
            [P_STOP_TIME] => 14:30
            [P_PLUS_DAY] => 3
            [P_NOT_1] => 0
            [P_NOT_2] => 0
            [P_NOT_3] => 0
        )
    [37] => Array
        (
            [P_1] => 0
            [P_2] => 0
            [P_3] => 0
            [P_START_TIME] => 
            [P_STOP_TIME] => 
            [P_PLUS_DAY] => 5
            [P_NOT_1] => 0
            [P_NOT_2] => 1
            [P_NOT_3] => 0
        )
)
```

Как мне выбрать подмассив [37] ?
40, 37 - это не индекс, а именно кастомные значения, т.е. в текущей реализации именно такой массив и приходит, код приведен полностью.
**UPD.** Я получаю указанный массив и также получаю переменную (например, $k), которая может быть равна или 40 или 37. Вот по совпадению её мне и нужно выбрать полностью соответствующий подмассив из массива.
Перерыл весь список функции работы с массивами, ближайшее что нашел - фильтр по индексу, но у меня индекса нет.

Comment: Сформулируйте конкретнее что хотите сделать и как вы собираетесь ловить нужное значение, если это не ключ и приходят кастомные значения...

Comment: Это [как-то так](https://jsfiddle.net/5nr1jgu7/) или нет?

Comment: Приходит указанный массив и также приходит переменная, которая может быть равна или 40 или 37. Вот по совпадению её мне и нужно выбрать полностью соответствующий подмассив из массива.